# Inkscape dialogue box

Tags: inkscape

I was drawing using Inkscape until I want to export my draw into image file, I faced this problem.

[image]

Bottom part of the dialogue box is being cut, and I have no idea how to access it.
It's seems to happen in several apps, Inkscape is just one of those.
Is there is a solution for this?

Comment: You could try to press and hold Alt, or Win-Key – then you might be able to drag the Window at other points than the title bar.
Just guessing though – I don't use wayland…

Comment: So… wich key is it? ;)

Comment: Is this wayland bug or just Linux bug? Hope there is permanent fix for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press and hold Alt or Super (depends on window manager) key – then you should be able to drag the window at other points than title bar.

Comment: Its Super (Windows) key. Please edit your answer. Thanks you very much.